# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix (External library)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gauge

i am creating my first app with Android Studio and java.
I want to add gauges to my project and i found a library called "sc-gauges" ([Github](https://github.com/Paroca72/sc-gauges)).
I added the maven repositorie and dependency to my build.gradle and i can see sc-gauges-2.6.4 in my External Libraries. I added an example from the github page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context="com.example.gauge.gauge.MainActivity">

<com.sccomponents.gauges.ScArcGauge
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    sc:angleStart="135"
    sc:angleSweep="270"
    sc:strokeSize="6dp"
    sc:progressSize="4dp"
    sc:value="45"
    sc:notches="8"
    sc:notchesLength="10dp"
    sc:textTokens="01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08"
    sc:pointerRadius="10dp"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the com.sccomponents.gauges.ScArcGauge works but for the sc: prefixes i get an error: Error:(12) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix. I feel like there is an easy fix, but since i am completely new to java programming and Android Studio i have not been able to find it.

Comment: Looks like the prefix "sc:" is not imported in the top layout like the others are… for example `xml:android` is imported and used below without any issues. Check out how to include that sccomponents thing into the constraint layout…

Comment: I was looking fot it but i couldn't find it.

Comment: @W0rmH0le gave the correct answer… automatic resource inclusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your xml file:

```
xmlns:sc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

At the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:sc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.gauge.gauge.MainActivity">
```